# Cumulative function of exponential bilateral function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative function of a Laplace distribution whose PDF is

---

$f_X(x)=\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda|x|},\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

---

I proved that, if $x<0$:

$\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda|x|}dx=[\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{\lambda x}]_{-\infty}^{x} =\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{\lambda x}$

But I have difficulties in the other case. I obtained, if $x\geq0$:

$\mathbb{P}(X\geq 0)=\mathbb{P}(X=0 \bigcup X>0)=\mathbb{P}(X=0)+\mathbb{P}(X>0)=\frac{\lambda}{2}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda|x|}dx=\frac{\lambda}{2}+[\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda x}]_{0}^{x}=\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda x}$

but I should have gotten $1-\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda x}$. 
Where i wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you integrating the $\frac{\lambda}{2}\mathrm{e}^{\lambda x}$?

Comment: @Chinny84 Sorry, i didn't understand the question.

Comment: For a continuous distribution, $\mathbb{P}\left(X = 0\right) \neq f_{X}\left(x\right)$. You should treat $\mathbb{P}\left(X = 0\right) = 0$.

Comment: @MarcoPittella the integral should be divided by $\lambda$. But you should see below.

Comment: I don't understand why. Maybe because, from the exponential distribution, $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx=1\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda x}dx=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x < 0$,

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{x}{\rm d}t~ \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |t|} = \frac{e^{\lambda x}}{2} \tag{1}
$$

For $x \ge 0$

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{x}{\rm d}t ~ \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |t|} &=& \color{blue}{\int_{-\infty}^{0}{\rm d}t ~ \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |t|}} + \color{red}{\int_{0}^{x}{\rm d}t ~ \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |t|}} \\
&=& \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}e^{\lambda\cdot 0}}  + \color{red}{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda x}} \\
&=& 1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda x} \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don't understand all passages. Could you made them more clear?

Comment: @MarcoPittella Sure, which part is unclear?

Comment: Above it was said of dividing by $\lambda$. In fact i don't understand why you eliminate, for $x<0$, the parameter from the numerator (not for nothing i wrote $\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{\lambda x}$). Then, i don't understand why for $x\geq0$ you start from $-\infty$. The half-line of negative reals should not be excluded for hypothesis?

Comment: @MarcoPittella I see, you are confused with the integral

$$
\int e^{\color{red}{a} x}{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{\color{red}{a}} e^{ax}
$$

Comment: Right, now I understood. Could you also explain me why, for $x\geq0$, you add the integral in blue? Aren't we trying to calculate for which probability the $x$ is positive?

Comment: @MarcoPittella Just to make a concrete example, imagine you want the cdf for $x = 1>0$, you need 

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{1}{\rm d}t ~ \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |t|} = \color{blue}{\int_{-\infty}^{0}{\rm d}t ~ \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |t|}} + \color{red}{\int_{0}^{1}{\rm d}t ~ \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |t|}}
$$

the first term you already know from the previous step. The second is what I have in Eq. (2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood the process but i can't get your same result. Applying the property that you said me, i write: $\mathbb{P}(X\geq0)=\int _{-\infty}^{0}f_X(x)dx+\int_{0}^{x}f_X(x)dx=\frac{e^{\lambda(0)}}{2}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda x}dx=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\int e^{-\lambda x}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\lambda}{2}[-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda x}]_0^x=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda x}-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda x}$. Where i wrong?

Comment: @MarcoPittella Almost there. Problem is the very last step

$$
\mathbb{P}(X \ge 0) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2}\left[-\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda x}\right]_0^x = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\left[e^{-\lambda x}  - 1\right] = \frac{1}{2}  - \frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda x} \color{red}{+\frac{1}{2}}
$$